# Compile all files in one, but don't compress

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm kind of new with GruntJS and currently adding Uglify to my project.

I've set it up so it compile all my JS  in one file but, for the dev time, I'ld like it not to compress the code.

Looking at [the doc](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#compress), I see there is a boolean option for it, but, even with:

```
...
options: {
  compress: false
}
...
```

It still compress it.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I use grunt-contrib-concat to concatenate, then grunt-contrib-uglify to minify the resulting concatenated file.

For reference, my concat task looks something like this:

```
concat : {
    options : {
        stripBanner : true
},
    head : {
        src : [header1.js, header2.js, header3.js],
        dest : ['/path/to/js/tmpfolder/', '<%=pkg.name %>.header.js'].join('/')
    },
    app : {
       src : [app1.js, app2.js, app3.js],
       dest : ['/path/to/js/tmpfolder/', '<%=pkg.name %>.app.js'].join('/')
    }
}
```

and my uglify task something like this:

```
uglify : {
    all : {
        options : {
            banner : "/*! <%= pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - <%= grunt.template.today(\"yyyy-mm-dd\") %> \n <%= pkg.author %> */",
            dead_code : true
    },
        files : uglifyFiles
     }
}
```

It's irritating, but I also need to define uglifyFiles, which I do like this:

```
uglifyFiles = {};
uglifyFiles['/path/to/js/tmpfolder/<%=pkg.name %>.header.min.js'] =  '/path/to/js/tmpfolder/<%=pkg.name %>.header.js';
uglifyFiles['/path/to/js/tmpfolder/<%=pkg.name %>.app.min.js'] = '/path/to/js/tmpfolder/<%=pkg.name %>.app.js';
```